# Skype business call equivalent to 'sip' for message

Tags: skype-for-business

I have an hyperlink in my mail signature to launch a Skype IM (sip:mememe@company.com); I would like to add one to a Skype call, not a call to a phone but a Skype to Skype call; I tried

callto:mememe@company.com
callto:sip:mememe@company.com
call:mememe@company.com

but no cigar. Does any one have an answer?

Comment: This requires a handler be configured on the destination system for that protocol. Unless Skype itself offers such a handler, it is unlikely you'll find the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
 <a href="skype:********?call">Link will initiate Skype to call my Skype username!</a>
```

Comment: Hello,

It's HTML, I've tried it nevertheless, does not work. Maybe there is no 'sip:' equivalent for a Skype call.

Comment: This will work only if the `skype:` protocol has been configured in the client's OS/e-mail client/browser.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Brian Folan is correct, according to the [Skype blog](https://blogs.skype.com/tips/2014/02/05/add-a-skype-call-to-action-to-your-website-or-email-signature/):

> Where you would enter a web address, enter skype: followed by your Skype name. If you want the link to start a chat instead of a call, add ?chat after your Skype name.

Comment: Hello,
I want to create a common hyperlink to launch a Skype call inside my organization; I have created one to launch an IM using 'sip:me@myorganization' that works; if I try the suggestion, it does not, either the HTML or the 'skype:me@myorganization' or the options that I posted before.

Thank you for your interest.